# How do I combine these two queries into a single INSERT INTO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Can someone tell me how can I combine these two queries into a single INSERT INTO query?

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `monthly_income`(`Year`, `Month`) VALUES (2017, 'September')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `monthly_income`(`totalincome`) SELECT SUM(Income) FROM `eventincome` WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-30'";
```

Here I want to insert all those values into a single row in the table "monthly_income". In Query2, i generate the total income between two dates from a **seperate table** called "eventincome". The "monthly_income" table has columns [Year, Month, totalincome]. And the "eventincome" table has columns [eventDate, eventTitle, Earnings, Expenses, Income]. So how can I join these two querys to use it in a

> mysqli_query($conn, parameter)

:)
PS: I want to set those values from those queries in the same row, without creating two seperate rows becuse of those two INSERT INTO's. That's why I wanna join/combine/merge(whatever) those two queries :)

Comment: PS: Both the queries work perfectly fine when run separately and gives the desired results :)

Comment: Unless you can amend so that you're setting values in the same columns of both rows, they will have to be 2 separate INSERT statements.

Comment: @user2486: It doesn't work :/

Comment: yeah I need to set those values in the same row @flauntster :)

Comment: @CryWolf95: not related to this question, but about the other one you deleted.  About DATE and VARCHAR.  VARCHAR change was good to identify the issue, but do not store dates as VARCHAR.  The DATE format can be sorted, queried on, used much more easily than VARCHAR.  And if you get tools or modules, they will not know how to manage your "date in a varchar" column.

Comment: @Nic3500: Thanks for sharing that knowledge, learned a good lesson from you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `monthly_income`(`totalincome`,`Year`, `Month`) SELECT SUM(Income),2017 as Year, 'September' as Month FROM `eventincome` WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-30'";
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RegBes it Works!! xoxo

Answer (score 0):

Add the values from the first query as constants in the second query...

`"INSERT INTO monthly_income(Year, Month,totalincome) SELECT 2017, 'September',SUM(Income) FROM eventincome WHERE eventDate BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-3'";`

Comment: Thank you for you help @Nick Fry, I will test this now also